# Rearranging 2 arrays with different lengths to create a third array Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, format

I have 2 arrays down below `a` and `b` the combine to make `result`. `a` is multiplied by `a_multiplier` and `b` gets multiplied by `b_multiplier`. `a` and `b` have different length arrays I want to combine and multiply them and rearange them in order of `a*a_multiplier, b*b_multiplier,a*a_multiplier.....`. How would I be able to modify the `result` function so that the Expected Output works?

```
import numpy as np 

a_multiplier = 3
b_multiplier = 5

a = np.array([5,32,1,4,3])
b = np.array([1,5,11,3])

result = np.vstack([a * a_multiplier, b * b_multiplier]).flatten("F")
```

Expected output:

```
[15  5 96 25  3 55 12 15 9]
```

Value Error:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 5 and the array at index 1 has size 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np

a_multiplier = 3
b_multiplier = 5

a = np.array([5,32,1,4,3])
b = np.array([1,5,11,3])

result = np.empty((a.size + b.size,), dtype=a.dtype)
result[0::2] = a * a_multiplier
result[1::2] = b * b_multiplier
```

Output:

```
array([15,  5, 96, 25,  3, 55, 12, 15,  9])
```